# Plotting solutions to Solve results

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a solution to a Solve result, ie I have a function f(x,y) and I want to plot y=y(x) for when f(x,y) = 0.06366. Here is what I am trying to do

```
f[x_, y_] := 0.5*Erf[(y - 0.04*x^2)/(0.1*Sqrt[x])] + 0.5;
Plot[Evaluate@Table[Solve[f[x, y] == 0.06366, {x, y}, {y, Range[0, 1, 0.2]}],
{x, 0, 7}], PlotRange -> Full]
```

Comment: Why not directly plot the expression in terms of `InverseErf[]` that you get from `Solve[]`?

Comment: I want to be able to do this for a general f(x,y)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like the following will do the job:

```
f[x_, y_] := 0.5*Erf[(y - 0.04*x^2)/(0.1*Sqrt[x])] + 0.5;
Plot[y /. Solve[f[x, y] == 0.06366, y], {x, 0, 7}]
```

I just copied the method from the "Solve" help page in Mathematica.

[image]